# MaskedEditValidator causes Page.IsValid to be false when using "en-GB" culture

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtDate" runat="server" Width="70" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date") %>'/>  
<atk:MaskedEditExtender ID="meeDate" CultureName="en-GB" runat="server" Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" TargetControlID="txtDate" PromptCharacter="_" />          
<atk:MaskedEditValidator ID="mevDate" runat="server" ControlExtender="meeDate" ControlToValidate="txtDate" EmptyValueMessage=" *" InvalidValueMessage="Date is invalid" IsValidEmpty="False" CssClass="validatorError" />
```

The following setup seems to work fine on the client side (the validator validates perfectly against dd/MM/yyyy), however when I post back and check Page.IsValid, the value is false.  I looked at mevDate.IsValid and it's false.  It seems that setting the CultulreName on the MaskedEditExtender is sufficient to get the MaskedEditValidator to emit the correct JavaScript, but on the server side of things it doesn't work.  When I flip CultureName to "en-US" everything works as expected, both on client and server.

**UPDATE**

One interesting thing I noticed is during debugging if you look at the MaskedEditValidator members, you’ll notice that the **private** member _Culture is set to “en-US” while the MaskedEditExtender is properly set to “en-GB”.  There doesn't seem to be a way to change this.

**UPDATE 2**

I ended up with the solution I posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the workaround I ended up with:

```
bool valid = true;
/* Only check Page.IsValid for USCulture, for other cultures MaskedEditValidator only properly works on the client-side 
 * (shows IsValid == false) on the server even though the date is in correct format and passed client side validation. */
if (USCulture)
{
    valid = Page.IsValid;
}
else
{
    /* Even though we are not checking Page.IsValid for non-us cultures, the server will trigger the validation anyway and on the 
     * postback the error message will display.  Here we simply set the .Text property to a HTML comment, for the browser to render nothing
     * as if there is no error.  Setting this property to empty/null causes the control to revert to the original message specified in .aspx. */
    mevCalendar.Text = "<!>";
}

if (valid)
{
    BindGridDataSource(pageNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug, that might be something you want to post on the ASP.NET forums...  there is a forum for the AJAX control toolkit there that the MS people listen too.

Comment: I posted there first actually, not getting much play at this point :)  Thank you.